Inconsistency using subsetting vs dplyr::filter
I have a data-frame which gives gives different results, depending on the filtering method used.. see screen shot below, which seems weird. Any thoughts on why this might be?


It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please do not post code or data in images

Could be the presence of NAs in the data?
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(x = factor(rep(c(1:3, NA), 5))) # 5 x 2

df |> filter(x == 2)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 1
#>   x    
#>   <fct>
#> 1 2    
#> 2 2    
#> 3 2    
#> 4 2    
#> 5 2
df[df$x == 2, ]
#> # A tibble: 10 × 1
#>    x    
#>    <fct>
#>  1 2    
#>  2 <NA> 
#>  3 2    
#>  4 <NA> 
#>  5 2    
#>  6 <NA> 
#>  7 2    
#>  8 <NA> 
#>  9 2    
#> 10 <NA>

Created on 2024-04-18 with reprex v2.1.0
This is noted at the top of the ?dplyr::filter help page:

Note that when a condition evaluates to NA the row will be dropped, unlike base subsetting with [.

